# gnupg 2.3.2 make error /home/ryan/Downloads/gnupg-2.3.2/common/sysutils.c:1263: undefined reference to `gpgrt_access'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, make

Trying to install the latest gnupg from source on Ubuntu 20.
My first ./configure found a few missing dependencies. I filled some of these through the package manager, others I installed from source.

Now my ./configure ends with this:

```
        GnuPG v2.3.2 has been configured as follows:

        Revision:  3bf8d7e1b  (15352)
        Platform:  GNU/Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

        OpenPGP:   yes
        S/MIME:    yes
        Agent:     yes
        Smartcard: yes (without internal CCID driver)
        TPM:       no 
        G13:       no
        Dirmngr:   no
        Keyboxd:   no
        Gpgtar:    yes
        WKS tools: yes

        Protect tool:       (default)
        LDAP wrapper:       (default)
        Default agent:      (default)
        Default pinentry:   (default)
        Default scdaemon:   (default)
        Default keyboxd:    (default)
        Default tpm2daemon: (default)
        Default dirmngr:    (default)

        Dirmngr auto start:  yes
        Readline support:    no
        LDAP support:        n/a
        TLS support:         no
        TOFU support:        no
        Tor support:         only .onion
```

looks fine i think

so i run sudo make and here's the last few lines of output:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ryan/Downloads/gnupg-2.3.2/kbx'
gcc -I/usr/local/include  -DKEYBOX_WITH_X509=1 -Wall -Wno-format-zero-length -Wno-pointer-sign -Wpointer-arith -g -O2   -o kbxutil kbxutil-kbxutil.o kbxutil-keybox-util.o kbxutil-keybox-init.o kbxutil-keybox-blob.o kbxutil-keybox-file.o kbxutil-keybox-search.o kbxutil-keybox-update.o kbxutil-keybox-openpgp.o kbxutil-keybox-dump.o ../common/libcommon.a -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lksba -lgpg-error -L/usr/local/lib -lgcrypt  -L/usr/local/lib -lgpg-error     
/usr/bin/ld: ../common/libcommon.a(libcommon_a-sysutils.o): in function `gnupg_access':
/home/ryan/Downloads/gnupg-2.3.2/common/sysutils.c:1263: undefined reference to `gpgrt_access'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:749: kbxutil] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ryan/Downloads/gnupg-2.3.2/kbx'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:631: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ryan/Downloads/gnupg-2.3.2'
make: *** [Makefile:551: all] Error 2
```

not too sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

> not too sure how to resolve this.

Well, *my personal choice* is to stay away from attempting things that put you in that kind of situation...

```
$ sudo apt install gnupg
```

... is much easier, and allows a clean uninstall if you find you do not need or want it anymore.
It might not be the very latest though, but that is seldom required for most features - unless there is a serious bug or flaw.

In the end; trying to compile complex software is prone to fail unless you really know "intimate" details about that actual software.

As always "knowledge is king".
So if you do not have the know-how, then  better keep it simple.

Comment: Using the package manager is definitely a preference. But for this scenario, I wanted to try the latest stable version as I've been having trouble capturing error output from gpg using bash syntax. I wondered if there was maybe past issues that had been resolved in newer versions. posted that issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775889/how-can-i-properly-capture-gpg-output-when-decrypting-files

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflicting older version of libgpg-error in a LD path, probably under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. Relink it to the new, e.g. :`ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0`
And yes, compiling gnupg from source is a miserable experience because of all the dependencies.